# findoneandupdate to update documents at multiple levels MongoDB + Node

Tags: node.js, mongodb

This is the schema, I would like to update the lastname of a person and metadata details at the same time. All this is dynamic, lastname is been passed from a front end application.

I am not able to update all the details within the same set `{}`. Could you please help me out

```
schema = {
    firstName : xxx,
    lastName  : yyy,
    middleName: zzz,
    metadata {
        updateDtTm : null,
        updatedBy  : 1,
        updateCount: 1
    }
}

----------------------------------------------------------------------------  

db.collection(updateObj.collName).findOneAndUpdate(updateObj.data, {
    $set: updateObj.newObj,
    $set:{
        'metaData.updateBy'  : updateObj.request.token.personId,
        'metaData.updateDtTm': now
    },
    $inc: {
        'metaData.updateCount': 1
    },
    function(err, res) {
        if (err) {
            reject("Couldnot update");
        } 
        else {
            resolve("updated")
        }
```

Comment: How does your front end object look like?

Comment: newvalues = {
      lastName: "zzz"
     }

Comment: and also what is the criteria for update?

Comment: your code is not complete. two closing brakets `}` are missing.

Comment: user = {
        firstName: "xxx"
  }

Comment: i have missed the brackets while pasting the code. But the code completely works fine. But i wanted the update to perform in same set func

Comment: I tried to add the metadata to the same object that comes ffrom front end.
updateObj.newObj= {
    'metaData.updateBy': updateObj.request.token.personId,
    'metaData.updateDtTm': now
  }
but this overwrites the data

Comment: if tried adding to the same object as below
updateObj.newObj.metaData.updateBy= updateObj.request.token.personId;
 but i get the below error
"Cannot set property 'updateBy' of undefined"